# Возврат на предыдущий фрагмент

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Имеется navigation drawer и фрагменты, как сделать так чтобы при нажатии стрелки назад возвращался предыдущий fragment, а не выход из приложения?

Comment: Добавлять фрагменты в транзакцию при создании.

Comment: Подробнее пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Меняя фрагменты, складывайте их в стек:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack("").commit();
```

Затем обработайте нажатие кнопки "Назад" в своей `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            // Здесь нужно доставать предыдущий фрагмент
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Чтобы достать предыдущий фрагмент используйте `mFragmentManager.popBackStack();`